# convert string to float considering all types of decimal separators

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I tried to create a function in java which can convert a string to float considering commas and point as decimal separators and thousand separator can be space, point or commas.
For example “998,4” should be displayed as 998.4, “998.4” should be displayed as 998.4
“7 899,45” should be displayed as 7899.45
“7.452,23” should be displayed as 7452.23
“7,123.12” should be displayed as 7123.12

```
public class converter {
 
    public static float convertToFloat(String input){
        String cleanedInput = input.replaceAll("[,\\s.]","");

        cleanedInput = cleanedInput.replaceFirst("[.,](?!.*[.,])",".");

        return Float.parseFloat(cleanedInput);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        String[] inputs = {"998,4", "998.4", "7 899,45", "7.452,23", "7,123.12"};
        for(String input:inputs){
            float result= convertToFloat(input);
            System.out.println("input:"+ input +"   " +"result:"+ result);
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: What is the problem with your solution?

Comment: And what about `1.234`? Is the dot a thousands separator or a decimal separator? In other words, how do you want to handle ambiguous cases?

Comment: For 1.234 should be considered point as decimal separator,so it should be remain the same

Comment: My solution take the hole number with all decimals and not display the decimals as well

Answer (score 0):

first of all, good job and nice problem :)
before I give you the solution I wanna point to your mistakes maybe you wanna try to solve it on your own.
first mistake, you are starting with cleaning the whole string, which removes all (//s,.) so how would you know where was the last (.,)
second mistake, you should replace last ,. with . not first (think about it)

and the solution would be something like this

```
    int lastIndex = Math.max(input.lastIndexOf(','), input.lastIndexOf('.'));
    String cleanedInput = input.substring(0, lastIndex).replaceAll("[,\\s.]","")
            .concat("."+input.substring(lastIndex+1).replaceAll(" ",""));
    return Float.parseFloat(cleanedInput);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a more sophisticated algorithm:

1. You need to define, which of your delimiters *can* be used as decimal comma. Does `" "` (a space) qualify for this?
2. Make sure that your input String is really just one number and not two different numbers that are separated by such a delimiter (again a space comes to my mind for this case).
3. When you are sure that your string contains only one number, remove all delimiters that cannot ever be used as decimal comma. You did this with your `String cleanedInput = input.replaceAll("[,\\s.]","");` - but always removed the `,` there.
4. Check, which of the remaining possible delimiters comes last, and also if it only is used once. If it is used more than once, and other delimiters occur before it, you are in trouble, you have a number with an invalid format. Either you can make this an error case (e.g. throw an exception) or you have a preference built into your code that handles this (e.g. ignore that kind of delimiter as if it was not a possible delimiter at all, just for this input). If everything else is OK, the single delimiter that occurred latest in the input string is your potential (!) decimal comma.
5. As further sanity check count if other delimiters are found before the one you found in step #4: if no, you could be in trouble, because if the delimiter found in step #4 is followed by exactly three digits, it also could be a thousands separator in a number that doesn't have digits after the decimal comma. Here you also have to either handle this as an error case or put a preference into your code (is it a comma or not)
6. Now you can remove all other delimiters than the one you found in step 4, replace the delimiter of step 4 with a character that your number-parser understands (take care, this can be locale-specific, so you should always specify the locale when finally parsing the number).

As you see it's not an easy task and several pitfalls await you. You might be able to optimize the algorithm if you can limit the variations of input that has to be handled.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you're first removing any *comma*, *\s*, or dot, from the string.

For example, *998,4*, becomes *9984*.
Thus, the subsequent call to *replaceFirst*, finds nothing, so it replaces nothing.

I believe what you are intending to do is, first remove the group separators, and then replace the decimal separator.

```java
String cleanedInput = input.replaceAll("[. ]","");
cleanedInput = cleanedInput.replace(",",".");
```

Although this will not work for the last condition, where the group and decimal separator symbols are swapped.

```
input:7,123.12   result:7.12312
```

You'll need to find their indices, to determine the number's format.

I created the following method, as an example.

```java
float parseFloat(String string) {
    string = string.replace(" ", "");
    int comma = string.indexOf(',');
    int dot = string.indexOf('.');
    if (comma != -1 && dot != -1) {
        if (comma < dot) return Float.parseFloat(string.replace(",", ""));
        else {
            string = string.replace(".", "");
            return Float.parseFloat(string.replace(",", "."));
        }
    } else if (comma != -1) return Float.parseFloat(string.replace(",", "."));
    else return Float.parseFloat(string.replace(".", ""));
}
```

Output

```
input:998,4   result:998.4
input:998.4   result:9984.0
input:7 899,45   result:7899.45
input:7.452,23   result:7452.23
input:7,123.12   result:7123.12
```

As a note, you could also use the *[NumberFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/text/NumberFormat.html)* class, with offers the *[parse](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/text/NumberFormat.html#parse(java.lang.String))* method.
Although, you would still need to know the initial format, prior to parsing the value.

Here is a basic example of parsing the format you're using.
You'll have to specify a *[Locale](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Locale.html)*—in this example I am using *Italy*, which uses this same format.

```java
Float parseFloat(String string) {
    NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.ITALY);
    try {
        return format.parse(string).floatValue();
    } catch (ParseException exception) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Output

```
input:998,4   result:998.4
input:998.4   result:9984.0
input:7 899,45   result:7.0
input:7.452,23   result:7452.23
input:7,123.12   result:7.123
```